# SQL statement stops after one insert

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm trying to insert into my database multiple times, but the INSERT sql statement works only the very first time it's called, then the execution continues without inserting. I don't know if that's relevant, but I'm getting that data from web scraping using Cheerio.

> This code runs fine, and produces no error. However it performs the
>   SQL query only once, the very first time it is called. Why?

Here's my code

```
remainingList.map(function (val) {

    const options = {
      uri: val,
      transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
      }
    };

    rp(options).then(($) => {
        title = $(".Lien5").text();
        price = $(".Texte8").text();
        contenu = $(".contenu").text();
    }).then(($) => {
        connection.query(`INSERT INTO WatchesList (url, title, price) VALUES ("${val}", "${title}", "${price}")`);
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in output?

Comment: Absolutely none. I even `console.log(title)` just to see, and it display the title each time correctly.

Comment: well, I know this wont answer your question, but I think it would be better, if you could construct the values list in the map function, and execute the INSERT INTO with the concataned values. You can do insert into (...) values (),(),() and so on, mysql support this also, I think. So one insert statement is better afterall.

Comment: Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mysql or https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql ?

Comment: How do you know that it performs the SQL query only once?

Comment: I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql, and I know it inserted into the database only once because there's only one new row

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

> Closing the connection is done using end() which makes sure all remaining queries are executed before sending a quit packet to the mysql server.

So try doing the following:

```
const insertPromises = remainingList.map(function (val) {

    const options = {
      uri: val,
      transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
      }
    };

    return rp(options).then(($) => {
        title = $(".Lien5").text();
        price = $(".Texte8").text();
        contenu = $(".contenu").text();
    }).then(($) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            connection.query(`INSERT INTO WatchesList (url, title, price) VALUES ("${val}", "${title}", "${price}")`, 
            (error) => {
                 if (error) {
                      reject();
                 } else {
                      resolve();
                 }                     
            });
        });
    });
});

Promise.all(insertPromises).then(() => connection.end());
```

Comment: @mokiliii Lo . Did the solution work? Please give us to know.